# how to do a complex replace in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the scenario:

```
dict = {'t1': 'm1', 'year': '2003'}
pattern = re.compile(r'#\{(.*?)\}')
str = "select * from records where year = #{year} and t1 = #{t1}"
```

What I want to do is to replace the `str` to **"select * from records where year = 2003 and t1 = m1"**

Could anyone tell me how to do it using python regex? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `{..}` instead of `#{..}`, you can use [`str.format_map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.format) or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> d = {'t1': 'm1', 'year': '2003'}
>>> fmt = "select * from records where year = {year} and t1 = {t1}"
>>> fmt.format_map(d) # available only in Python 3.2+
'select * from records where year = 2003 and t1 = m1'
>>> fmt.format(**d)
'select * from records where year = 2003 and t1 = m1'
```

---

Regular expression solution: Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with the replacement function as the second argument.

```
>>> d = {'t1': 'm1', 'year': '2003'}
>>> fmt = "select * from records where year = #{year} and t1 = #{t1}"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'#\{(.*?)\}', lambda m: d[m.group(1)], fmt) # m -> match object
'select * from records where year = 2003 and t1 = m1'
```